# Keep on getting weird, random "Install failed" messages on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, popups

I keep on getting weird messages saying it can't install something from my temp folder.
I have zero idea what could be causing it.

[image]

Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎8/‎1/‎2021
OS build    19045.2965
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Comment: Run deep antivirus scans with your antivirus and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Comment: Is the executable you are running, that generates the temporary data in question, properly signed? In other words, is whatever you are trying to install, properly signed by the author?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not trying to run anything.
Just pops up randomly.

Comment: @theblitz - You have something trying to be installed. Impossible to determine based on the temporary filename in the screenshot.

Comment: It's not "random", something is likely trying to autoupdate. Try looking in Windows event log, maybe there's some more info.

Comment: @theblitz If it is fixed please let us know, I agree with harrymc. You might want to run sfc.exe /scannnow [System File Checker] after it is solved, in case something was replaced or deleted.

Comment: @vssher Because of work pressure I haven't had time to check (it's on my home computer). Will check tonight. One thing I might try is to start up in Safe Mode and completely clean out my Temp folder.

Comment: @vssher So, I looked in the event log and nothing stands out. I also started up in safe mode to delete everything in my Temp folder to no avail. One other thing I tried was to uninstall a couple of things I installed earlier this week. Still no good. :( Avast and MalwareBytes found nothing

Comment: You might want to try something a bit more rougher I have always had a good clean experience using DR. WEB https://www.drweb.com/ It is created from Russian programmer, though, which some people in the United States try to avoid. I try to be open minded. :) It cleans a lot better than most Anti-virus softwares and it is FREE. Hope you solve this. Peace!

Comment: @vssher It asks me to uninstall Avast. Can't do that.

Comment: Avast isn't very good. Losing it is no loss.

Comment: @music2myear Thing is I use it as my password store

Comment: There are better tools for that also. I recommend KeePass or BitWarden.

Comment: For some reason it just seems to have stopped. Weird. Maybe all the rubbish I deleted helped.